# Group and sum day by day

Tags: mongodb

This is how my collection structure looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57589d2a9108dace306602b8"),
    "IDproject" : NumberLong(53),
    "email" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "dc" : ISODate("2016-06-06T22:33:13.000Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57589d2a9108dace306602b8"),
    "IDproject" : NumberLong(53),
    "email" : "david.doe@gmail.com",
    "dc" : ISODate("2016-06-07T22:33:13.000Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57589d2a9108dace306602b8"),
    "IDproject" : NumberLong(53),
    "email" : "elizabeth.doe@gmail.com",
    "dc" : ISODate("2016-06-078T22:33:13.000Z")
}
```

As you can see, there are two customers added on June 7th and one on June 6th. I would like to group and sum these results for the last 30 days.

It should looks something like this:

```
{
  "dc" : "2016-06-05"
  "total" : 0
}

{
  "dc" : "2016-06-06"
  "total" : 1
}

{
  "dc" : "2016-06-07"
  "total" : 2
}
```

As, you can see, there are no records on June 6th, so it's zero. It should be zero for June 5th, etc.

That would be the case #1, and the case #2 are following results:

```
  {
      "dc" : "2016-06-05"
      "total" : 0
   }


   {
      "dc" : "2016-06-06"
      "total" : 1
   }


  {
      "dc" : "2016-06-07"
      "total" : 3
   }
```

I've tried this:

```
db.getCollection('customer').aggregate([
{$match : { IDproject : 53}},    
{ $group: { _id: "$dc", total: { $sum: "$dc" } } }, ]);
```

But seems complicated. I'm first time working with noSQL database.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay. This is much better:

`db.getCollection('customer').aggregate([
    {$match : { IDproject : 53}},    
    { $group: { _id: "$dc", total: { $sum: 1 } } },
]);`

Just need to figure out how to add a zero to total number, and get only last 30 days, but case 2# is still there.

Comment: Why do you care about the the days in the last 30 days where there is no record?

Comment: Because I need to show that on the graph.

Comment: However, I can handle it by PHP, but curious how to sum day by day (case #2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you will get daily counts (the common idiom for row count is `{$sum: 1}`).

However, you cannot obtain zeros for days that are lacking data – because there is no data that would give the grouping key for these days. You must handle these cases in PHP by generating a list of desided dates and then looking if there's data for that each date.

```
db.getCollection('customer').aggregate([
    {$match : { IDproject : 53}},    
    {$group: { 
       _id: {year: {$year: "$dc"}, month: {$month: "$dc"}, day: {$dayOfMonth: "$dc"}}},
       total: {$sum: 1} 
    }}, 
]);
```

Note that MongoDB only operates in the UTC timezone; there are no aggregation pipeline operators that can convert timestamps to local timezones reliably. The `$year`, `$month` and `$dayOfMonth` operators give the date in UTC which may not be the same as in the local timezone. Solutions include:

1. saving timestamps in the local timezone (= lying to MongoDB that they are in UTC),
2. saving the timezone offset with the timestamp,
3. saving the local year, month and dayOfMonth with the timestamp.